# Docusign Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body: {"error":"consent_required"}

Tags: docusignapi

Added supported `scopes` by `docusign` for `integration key` in admin connected app still getting consent required error:

Here is whatever `scopes` added against `integration key`
[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I claimed the domain and added impersonation scope, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @pootzko, I was also getting the same error even after the domain has claimed. Solved when removed users registered under this account and added again them back and then issue resolved. I don't know the actual reason but this worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organization-level consent requires a [claimed domain](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains), and will only apply to users with email addresses under that domain.

Answer (score 6):

Drew is correct. In addition, you need to include the `impersonation` scope if you're using JWT grant with the integration key (client id)