# Docusing Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body: {"error":"consent_required"}

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I got this error while request JWT token.

Step: 1
so i request to
"https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id={clinet_id}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44333/ds/login?authType=JWT#/username"

Step:2
Redirect To me on authorized page
[image]

Step: 3
Afte Accept redirect on login page and again try to Authorzation with JWT token but still getting same error as above.

[image]

setting on docusign as per below i gave Permissions for "signature impersonation" in my docusign account.

[image]
[image]

can you please help me what i wrong in it. i check another linked also "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713136/docusign-error-while-requesting-server-received-a-non-successful-http-code-comp" but i already include the impersonation scope but don't know why always getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urvish, this is a bug I'm fixing it right now. I'll have the fixed version out ASAP. I saw you also posted - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/issues/24 so I'll close this issue when the bug is fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Update: this should be fixed now if you get latest from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer Inbar Gazit. now it working